# Can I trust a variable voltage step down converter to hold at a fixed voltage

Tags: step-down, production

I need a 70 watt capable 76 volt DC-DC supply. I cannot seem to find any readily available on the market, so I considering buying a step down converter such as the one pictured below and setting it to 7 volts. this will be for a low volume production device. My question is how much can i trust this device to stay set at 7 volts if I use the built in adjustable potentiometer. I know I can have a fuse in place in case the voltage rises suddenly, but I am mainly interested in how stable of a voltage output these products provide once set.

The device below is not the one I plan to buy, it is there as an example of a device governed by a small on board potentiometer.

[image]

Comment: If you need a 76 V capable converter, why do you present a 38 V model? If you need 70W at 7V, why do you present a 5A model?

Comment: this is just an example of a device governed by a small on board potentiometer. This is not the device I plan to buy

Comment: If you look at the coil, you see solder drops glued to the wire and vibrations will damage the insulation of the winding because the coil touches the small aluminum heat sink. The heat sink will soon leave the circuit anyway, need more?

Comment: Sorry, your question was about the multiturn potentiomenter. In my experience they are very stable, fully protected against humidity, ok.

Comment: The modules however are of unknown quality. You should ask the sellers what data they give and guarantee on their modules. The voltage stability depends on a lot of other factors than the multi-turn pot. If you buy random ebay garbage, that is what you will get, no data, no specs, no guarantees.

Comment: While that does look like a cautionary tale of cheap, OP will presumably use UR-Recognized modules for units actually sold.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, fixed resistors are more stable than pots.

But in this application, the noise of the pot is inconsequential, leading only to small jumps/drifts that are well within typical input voltage tolerances of receiving devices.

In fact, as you manually set the output to your liking, it is probable that the result will be closer to the nominal voltage than you can buy from a fixed voltage converter, which is often only 1% accurate or worse.